# explain java transformation in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Hi all am using a java transformation in my mapping and added the code in it

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
     EMP_NAME1=">>"+EMP_NAME+"<<";
     EMP_ID1=EMP_ID;
}
```

I expect the rows should be inserted 3 times.

But it is done once,string concatenated with `>> <<`.

Also can anyone explain me what is the difference between active and passive java transformation.

I have created the passive one in any case will it be the reason?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `generateRow()` inside the loop. Java transformation emits a new row every time this function is executed.

*Active* transformations change the number of rows passing through them. On the contrary, if the number of input rows is equal to output rows, then the transformation is called *passive*. You should use the former.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use generateRow function to generate new records.

A sample program to create new records for student and their subject marks can be found as below.

```
String [] sub_list;
String sub_delimiter =”,”;
String [] subject_mark;
string mark_delimiter = “=”;
sub_list = SUBJECT_WITH_MARKS.split(sub_delimiter);
o_STUDENT_NO= STUDENT_NO;
for (int i=0; i < sub_list.length ;i++) {
subject_mark = sub_list.split(mark_delimiter );
o_SUBJECT =subject_mark[0];
o_MARK =Double.parseDouble(subject_mark[1]);
generateRow();
}
```

You can see [how to use java transformation in informatica](http://tutorialcorner.com/2015/12/split-column-to-row-in-informatica-with-java-transformation/) for more details.